# Power Apps - Create Unique List of Collection

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-formula, powerapps-collection

I have a collection called as TestCol and it looks like this.

```
Name      ID      ToAddress                                                        Status
Abc       123     asdfg@example.com,koldef@example.com,asdasdasfda@example.com        A        
Def       234     nanasd@example.com,asdfg@example.com                                A
Ghi       567     asdfg@example.com,asdasfg1@example.com                              B
```

I want to create a new collection Called as UniqueToAddress like,

```
ToAddressUnique
asdfg@example.com
koldef@example.com
asdasdasfda@example.com
nanasd@example.com
asdasfg1@example.com
```

It can be seen that **asdfg@example.com** is repeated multiple times inside the ToAddress and it appears only once on ToAddressUnique Collection. How Can I do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following expression to generate a list of unique addresses:

```
Distinct(
    Split(
        Concat(TestCol, ToAddress, ","),
        ","),
    Result)
```

The idea is to first concatenate (using the [Concat function](https://learn.microsoft.com/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-concatenate)) all the addresses in your collection, then split the long string (using the [Split function](https://learn.microsoft.com/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-split)), and finally take only the unique addresses using the [Distinct function](https://learn.microsoft.com/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-distinct) to get what you need.

Hope this helps!